# Why can't I see text in activity_main.xml when I create a new Android Studio project?

Tags: java, android

Hi I'm new to `Android Studio` and am running into some trouble with starting a new project. I want to design an app, but unfortunately I cannot see any of the components I place in the `ConstraintLayout`.

Has anyone else experienced this? I've tried reinstalling the program and have also watched a few videos without much luck.

Update: 7.1.2018 7:22pm

[Design Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkWqt.png)
[Text Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yU5s.png)

Comment: I see some red flags in your `TextView`. Could you show us the `xml` file, the text tab?

Comment: Is this question related to JavaScript? Because JavaScript is one of the tags.

Comment: No. This has nothing to do with js

Comment: I posted the pictures of that same scenario recreated with 'editText3' and 'editText4' edit text components @DforTye

Comment: You have provided the same pics :) @CormacKennedy

Comment: Sorry fixed it! @DforTye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem in `Android Studio`.

Just go to `styles.xml` file and change:

[image: styles]

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

The keyword here is to add `Base`

[image: base]

[image: result]